# Исправка кода бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, дерево

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int tabs = 0;
queue <int *> myqueue;

struct Branch {
  int Data;
  Branch *LeftBranch;
  Branch *RightBranch;
};

void addToTree(int aData, Branch *&aBranch);
void print(Branch *aBranch);
int find(Branch *Root, int *N);

int main() {

  int* N = new int;
  cout << "Enter number for find in tree" << endl;
  cin >> *N;
  cin.get();

  Branch *Root = 0;
  int* arr = new int[15];

  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 198 - 99;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    addToTree(arr[i], Root);
  }
  find(Root, N);
  print(Root);
  return 0;
}
void addToTree(int aData, Branch *&aBranch) {
  if (!aBranch) {
    aBranch = new Branch;
    aBranch->Data = aData;
    aBranch->LeftBranch = 0;
    aBranch->RightBranch = 0;
    return;
  }
  else if (aBranch->Data > aData) {
    addToTree(aData, aBranch->LeftBranch);
  }
  else {
    addToTree(aData, aBranch->RightBranch);
  };
}

void print(Branch *aBranch) {
  if (!aBranch) return;

  tabs++;
  print(aBranch->LeftBranch);

  for (int i = 0; i < tabs; i++) cout << " ";
  cout << aBranch->Data << endl;

  print(aBranch->RightBranch);
  tabs--;
  return;
}
int find(Branch *Root, int n) {

  if (Root->Data % n == 0) {
    myqueue.push(&Root->Data);
    return 0;
  }
  if (Root->LeftBranch->Data < n) {
    return find(Root->LeftBranch, n);
  }
  else {
    return find(Root->RightBranch, n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Помогите исправить код.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: +1 - за слово "исправка"

Comment: В чем смысл возвращаемого значения функции `find`, если она всегда возвращает `0`? В чем вообще смысл функции `find`? Что именно она должна искать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сигнатура функции `int find(Branch *Root, int *N);` не соответствует сигнатуре реализованной функции `int find(Branch *Root, int n)`. Соответственно компилятор не находит определения подходящей функции `find` и ругается. Объявление и реализацию можно было бы и не разносить.

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявляете функцию

```
int find(Branch *Root, int *N);
```

и вызываете именно ее!

```
find(Root, N);  // N - int*
```

Но реализуете совсем другую функцию...

```
int find(Branch *Root, int n) {
    if (Root->Data % n == 0) {
    ...
```

Согласуйте объявление и определение...